# IF siempre devuelve el mismo resultado

Tags: c++

Resulta que tengo que ingresar los nombres y notas de 20 alumnos y, a medida que ambos datos ingresan, el programa me tiene que decir si están aprobados o aplazados (reprobados).
Mi problema es que el programa siempre me dice que están reprobados a pesar de que tengan nota 10 o parecidas.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    int i,alumno;
    float nota;
    char nombre[20];
    printf("\t\t SISTEMA DE CALIFICACIONES\n\n");
    printf("Indicar la cantidad de alumnos: ");
    scanf("%d",&alumno);
    for(i=1;i<=alumno;i++)
        {
            printf("Ingresar nombre del alumno: ");
            fflush(stdin);
            gets(nombre);
            printf("Ingresar calificacion: ");
            scanf("%.2f",&nota);
        if(nota < 4)
            {
                printf("Aplazado \n");
            }
        else
            {
                printf("Aprobado \n");
            }
        }
system("pause");
return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Porque lo estas leyendo como `%.2f`, prueba con `%f`.

Comment: @Pablochaches Muchas gracias, era ese el problema, lo había puesto así porque tengo entendido que es para que solo me aparezca dos decimales

Comment: Nunca entenderé por que no hacen la respuesta... EN LA ZONA DE RESPUESTA !! literalmente es explicar lo mismo, copiar y pegar, y editar el error.

Comment: @Excorpion Lo vi tan pequeño que no considere necesario pasarlo, pero tienes razon, ahora lo paso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

aunque no es parte de tu pregunta, trata de usar solo las librerías que necesitas, en cuanto a tu pregunta es como dice Pablochanches, usa %f al leer datos de tipo float.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    int i,alumno;
    float nota;
    char nombre[20];
    printf("\t\t SISTEMA DE CALIFICACIONES\n\n");
    printf("Indicar la cantidad de alumnos: ");
    scanf("%d",&alumno);
    for(i=1;i<=alumno;i++)
    {
            printf("Ingresar nombre del alumno: ");
            fflush(stdin);
            gets(nombre);
            printf("Ingresar calificacion: ");
            scanf("%f",&nota);
        if(nota < 4)
            {
                printf("Aplazado \n");
            }
        else
            {
                printf("Aprobado \n");
            }
    }
system("pause");
return 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo que pasa es que estas usando un formato incorrecto. En lugar de `%.2f` tienes
que usar `%f`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    int alumno;
    float nota;
    char  nombre[20];
    printf("\t\t SISTEMA DE CALIFICACIONES\n\n");
    printf("Indicar la cantidad de alumnos: ");
    scanf("%d", &alumno);
    for (int i = 0; i < alumno; i++) {
        printf("Ingresar nombre del alumno: ");
        fflush(stdin);
        gets(nombre);
        printf("Ingresar calificacion: ");
        scanf("%f", &nota);
        if (nota < 4) {
            printf("Aplazado \n");
        } else {
            printf("Aprobado \n");
        }
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```